# Highcharts Gantt avoid tooltip closure when moving cursor outside Gantt

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts, highcharts-gantt

Hi I have a Gantt chart where I have implemented a custom tooltip that appear/disappear when the user clicks on an event.

I'm using angular2-highcharts

This works great !

The problem is that when the tooltip is very big and when it is rendered half on the Gantt area and half OUTSIDE the Gantt area and the user moves the cursor **outside the Gantt... The tooltip disappear**.

How can I prevent this behavior ?

Just to be clear, if you check the image below: if I move the cursor below the redline, the tooltip disappear

[image]

Thanks to support

This is the stackblitz with the code:

https://highcharts-angular-gantt-6jausr.stackblitz.io

https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-gantt-6jausr

Comment: Hi, your tooltip look like created custom not typical for Gantt chart. I need to see your chart configuration, please prepare a simplified example of your case in the online code editor.

Comment: ok, I will prepare a stackblick and I'll be back to you

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-gantt-6jausr

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behavior of a tooltip that is active when you hover over the point. You need to set **`stickOnContact: true`** if you want to prevent the tooltip from switching or closing when touched or pointed.

**Live demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-gantt-4urdh9

**API References:**
https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/tooltip.stickOnContact

Comment: actually this is not working, if you check, when you the tooltip is opened and you move the cursor outsite the gantt tabel, the tooltip disappears

Comment: It's also normal behavior for tooltip. Your tooltip's more custom and if you want to prevent close, you might try to edit core code. https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts